# how to make dynamically resizeable textbox with tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make dynamically resizable Textbox widget in tkinter.
How to make it add another line when the line is full and vice versa remove line if I decide to delete content. I have tried to add `<KeyRelease>` bind and partly it worked, I got something like that:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont

def breakline(event):
    inp = event.widget.get(1.0, 'end-1c')
    font = tkFont.Font(size=event.widget['font'].split(' ')[-1])
    TextWidth = font.measure('0') * event.widget['width']
    InpWidth = font.measure(inp)
    if inp and not InpWidth % TextWidth:
        if event.widget['height'] != InpWidth // TextWidth:
            event.widget['height'] = InpWidth // TextWidth
    elif event.widget['height'] != InpWidth // TextWidth + 1:
        event.widget['height'] = (InpWidth // TextWidth) + 1


win = tk.Tk()

x = tk.Text(win, height=1, width=30, font='12')
x.bind('<KeyRelease>', breakline)

x.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
win.mainloop()
```

But it did not work as I wanted either as It only executes when I release the button, so if I tried to spam, it would add lines lately. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Try virtual event `<<Modified>>` instead of `<KeyRelease>`, but you need to call `event.widget.edit_modified(0)` at the end of `breakline()`.

Comment: Thanks. Worked just like I wanted.